# How to return the elements in an arraylist that's in an arraylist

Tags: java

```
static int minValueOfElements(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> input){
    // Return the minimum value in the input list of lists (matrix)
    return 0;
}
```

I need to get all the elements that are in the Array List so for example :

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

needs to return 1.

There is one Array List and that contains Array Lists that have elements in them. So I need to find out how to get all those elements.

Comment: Loop through `input`.

Comment: Hint : Look at `ArrayList.addAll()` to merge all  list together and comparaison will be easy

Comment: Your question is unclear.  In one place you want _"to get all those elements"_, but earlier you want to _"return 1"_. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Integer getMinimumOfListOfLists(List<List<Integer>> listOfLists) {

    List<Integer> mergedList = new ArrayList<>();
    //merge all
    for(int i=0; i<listOfLists.size(); i++) {
        mergedList.addAll(listOfLists.get(i));
    }

    //sort
    Collections.sort(mergedList);

    // return first element from sorted list - this will be the smallest element
    return mergedList.get(0);

}
```

This answer is to get the minimum element out of all elements in all lists. not sure from the question what you were looking for exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to get you means:
I think the first we should flatten the list and then get the max element.
If you are using JDK7, I suggestion use Guava to solve it.
If you are using JDK8 it will very easy.
Here is the example:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FlattenCollection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> wrapList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> first = new ArrayList<>();
        first.add(1);
        first.add(2);

        List<Integer> second = new ArrayList<>();
        second.add(3);
        second.add(4);

        wrapList.add(first);
        wrapList.add(second);

        System.out.println(wrapList);

        //JDK7
        List<Integer> result1 = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.concat(wrapList));//flatten list
        System.out.println(result1);
        Integer max1 = Collections.max(result1);//max element
        System.out.println(max1);

        //JDK8
        List<Integer> result2 = wrapList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());//flatten list
        System.out.println(result2);
        Integer max2 = result2.stream().max((o1, o2) -> o1 - o2).get();//max element
        System.out.println(max2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
4
```